# Representing a number in Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Given a very large number $F$ which is a repetition of a number $N$ , $M$ number of times. Is there a way to represent that number in form of geometric series.

For eg - $F=321321321\cdots 321$ where $321$ is repeated $100$ times.  Then $F=321(100100100100\cdots 1001) = 321(100^{99}+100^{98}+\cdots+100+1)$

Is there a general Formula for a given $F,N,M$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric series is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^M x^i=\frac{x^{M+1}-1}{x-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So the formula you seek is
\begin{eqnarray*}
F= N\frac{x^{M+1}-1}{x-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
In your example $N=321$ , $M=99$ and $x=1000$.

Comment: Where is $N$ in this formula and how is $x$ determined ?

Comment: Sorry Sammy ... typos corrected now ? $x$ is determined by asking what do I need to multiply by to get enough zero to add on the next repetition of $N$.

Comment: @sammy Hint: This problem solves the $(100^{90}+100^{98}+\dots+100+1)$ problem.  Now multiply in the $N$ for your desired result.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt make your first exponent $99$ not $90$.

Comment: Is $x$ = $10$ power(No. of digits in integer) ?

Comment: @sammy Yes that is right $x=10 to the power of (# digits in 321)$ ... $1000$ in this case.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Uh, you sure?  I took that directly from the problem

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I was wrong last time ... I am right this time ... ha ha